# Download the middle of a file using python requests

Tags: python, download, python-requests

What I am trying to accomplish is to download a specific portion of a video file using python. Sort of what a browser will do when playing a video. If the file is 1000 Bytes, I want to download from byte 200 to 700. I know that I can download the file in parts using the method below:

```
file_ = open(filename, 'wb')
res = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for chunk in res.iter_content(amount):
    file_.write(chunk)
file_.close()
```

How can I modify this code to accomplish that?

Comment: Use a context manager to handle files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server has to support this:

> If `Accept-Ranges` is present in HTTP responses (and its value isn't
>   `none`), the server supports range requests. You can check this by
>   issuing a HEAD request.

If the server supports it you can request the part as

```
curl http://i.imgur.com/z4d4kWk.jpg -i -H "Range: bytes=0-1023"
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Also take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121314/download-only-a-part-of-a-file).

Comment: Thanks, this method worked... I a downloaded part of a video but I cannot play the file , do you know why this happens?

Comment: Which player did you try? https://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm some might be able to start from a "corrupt beginning", when you did not start exactly at a chunk and skip that.

Comment: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/379892-How-to-Watch-Half-Downloaded-Video

Comment: @jinyus Did you find the solution? I too am having similar issue when I downloaded part of file but doesn't play and am completely stuck. Pls help